# Prove $|\prod_{i=1}^n a_i - a_n^n|\leq 2n\delta$ if $0 \leq a_i \leq 1$ and $|a_i - a_{i+1}| \leq \delta$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, upper-lower-bounds

How to prove the following?

If $0 \leq a_i \leq 1$ and $|a_i - a_{i+1}| \leq \delta$ for all $i<n$, then
$$\Big|\prod_{i=1}^n a_i - a_n^n \Big| \leq 2n\delta.$$

I have run numerical experiments and it seems the above is true.

Comment: This is false if $\delta$ is allowed to be large.

Comment: $\delta \leq 1$ since $0\leq a_i \leq 1$.

Comment: You should add that to the hypothesis .We also have $|a_i-a_{i+1}| \leq 10,000$ so $\delta$ can be large.

Comment: The inequality folows easily from the following: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125664/show-that-prod-i-1n-a-i-prod-j-1n-b-i-sum-t-1n-1-prod-i-le?rq=1

Comment: The condition that $0\leq a_i \leq 1$ is already there, from which you can deduce that $\delta \leq 1$.

Comment: What kind of reasoning is that? You cannot conclude that $\delta \leq 1$ even if $a_i=0$ for all $i$.

Comment: If $0\leq x \leq 1$ and $0\leq y \leq 1$, then it is obvious that $|x-y|\leq 1$, right?

Comment: Thanks for the reference. But I don't see how the inequality follows easily from it.

Comment: What have you tried? My first instinct is induction, but personally I'm in a lazy mood. It's your question so you're not allowed to be lazy about it. Give induction a go...

Comment: Yes. I tried induction. It doesn't work for me. The problem is the new term $|a_{n}^n - a_{n+1}^n |\leq \delta n$, which can't the make induction consistent.

Comment: @user3750444 Please note that you shouldn't change the original question *well after* it has been asked and people have invested time into answering it. Otherwise you can keep changing the question every time someone answers the new version of your question, and it gets confusing because the answers don't match the question because you keep changing the goalpost i.e. the question. Please revert the question back to what it was and ask the proposition as a new question. See here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177173/how-to-deal-with-questions-that-change?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: You can't deduce $\delta \leq 1$, given $a_i \leq 1$, the same **faulty** reasoning will yield $\delta \leq n$, for any $n \in \mathbb N$. Notice, $0\leq x,y,\leq 1$ implies $|x-y|\leq 1 \leq n$ for each $n\gt 1$.

Comment: If you let $n=\delta$ the inequalities will still hold.

Comment: @AdamRubinson OK. I will revert it back.

Answer (score 2):

The proposition is false. Take $a_1 = \frac{1}{2},\ a_2 = \frac{1}{2},\ n=2, \delta = 0,$ so that the condition $|a_i - a_{i+1}| \leq \delta$ for all $i<2$ is satisfied.

Then, $$ \Big|\prod_{i=1}^n a_i - a_n^n \Big| = \big\vert a_1 - a_2^2 \big\vert\ \cdot\ \big\vert a_2 - a_2^2 \big\vert =  \Bigg\vert \frac{1}{2} - \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \Bigg \vert\ \cdot\ \Bigg\vert \frac{1}{2} - \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \Bigg\vert = \frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{4} \not\leq 2\cdot 2\cdot 0 = 0.$$

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the proposition. Please have a look now.

Comment: @user3750444 No, you shouldn't change a question *well after* it has been asked and people have invested time into answering it.

Comment: Sorry, I won't do it again! Thank you very much!